# Bulk Insert Polish signs

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio, character-encoding, special-characters

I'm am inserting a data from .txt to local database in VisualStudio 2013 with polish signs with a `BULK INSERT` but it doesn't show all polish characters. I know that this command doesn't support `UTF-8`, so I convert my file to `UTF-16 LE BOM`, via SublimeText2, I got only one polish sing which is `ó`, but I can't get the one with "tails" - for instance i have in my data `ą` and i get an `a`. I tried a lot of other encoding for this file and none seems legit. Query for this is :

```
BULK INSERT Ksiazki
FROM 'C:\Users\Ryżyk\Desktop\PratchettApp\BazaDanychPl.txt' 
WITH 
(
 DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar',
 FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
 ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
 );
```

Comment: How does VisualStudio specify character set?  Sounds like it is `latin1`, not `utf8` (since it could handle `ó` but not the others).

Comment: Don't use `UTF-16` for anything.  Use only `utf8`.

Comment: I don't know, where I could check it? `UTF 8` is not supported by `Bulk  Insert` and I don't get any special characters when I use it.